# It is correct to say “ i will report your office sunday for start my duty “

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases

I want to tell him that i will come to your office on sunday to start my duty

Comment: Do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?” and “is this correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”, and the *[Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*.

Answer (score 1):

"I will report to your office on Sunday to start my duty."